# not able to share url in facebook using angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, facebook-social-plugins, prerender, rendertron

While using angular 7 is it even possible to share url in facebook without using server side rendering module as angular universal or prerender ?
I tried updating meta tags required for facebook share during share click function but still it's not working. What is the best way to successfully implement facebook share of angular 7 page( data is coming from api) ?

I am trying to implement [Rendertron](https://medium.com/@abdelrhman.elgreatly/angular-single-page-app-seo-friendly-using-rendertron-24592fa731b6) but I am not able to run the project. I tried step by step process listed in the link but still no success.

Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ngx-share module.
You can find ngx-share at [here](https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-sharebuttons/#/)

Comment: but ngx-share module still needs server side rendering module (Angular Universal or Rendertron) to set dynamic meta tags.
https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-sharebuttons/#/faq

Comment: In my opinion you need to use server side rendering module or create that sharing page on server side to avoid meta tags issues.